# No route matches [POST] "/" のエラーが出る

Tags: ruby-on-rails

以下のようにログイン認証を実装したいのですが、ユーザー名とパスワードを入れログインボタンを押すと、以下のようなエラーが表示されてしまいます。解決策を教えて下さい。

```
No route matches [POST] "/"
```

~routes.rb~

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'
  get 'users/show'
  get 'users/index'
  root :to => "sessions#index"
end
```

~views/sessions/new.html.rb~

```
<h1>Log in</h1><%= form_tag  do %>
<div class="field"><%= label_tag :name, 'login name' %>
  <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>
</div><div class="field"><%= label_tag :pass, 'password' %>
  <%= password_field_tag :pass , params[:pass]%>
</div><div class="actions"><%= submit_tag "ログイン" %>
</div><% end %>
```

~sessions_controller.rb~

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

    def index
        render "new"
    end

    def create
      user = User.find_by_name params[:name]
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:pass])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to "users/index"
      else
        flash.now.alert = "Invalid"
        render "new"
      end
     end

    def destroy
      session[:user_id] = nil
      redirect_to "/users/index"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

"/" に対する POST を定義するには、config/routes.rb に

```
post "/" => "sessions#index"
```

と記載してください。

ルーティングは `rake routes` で確認できます。